# Capturing data in clip from smaller extent

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.0, clip

What I am trying to perform is a clip what captures the shoreline on a town in CT. I have the town boundary and I can use the buffer to extrude the polygon but I have wondering if there was an easier way.

[image: This is the image of the town]

[image: This is the image of the town with the data I want to clip]

as you can see its the negative space in the boundary of the town polygon that I am hoping the fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this (with a basic license) is with the Union tool. Create a polygon that contains the entire shoreline and extent to which you need the sea to cover.

[image]

Then use this new feature and your land feature as input to the tool. This should result in a new feature class that contains various features, of which one should be the sea boundary you need.
[image]

Delete all the other features you do not need. 
[image]